# Webservice not working in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have created a webservice in Visual studio 2010.I have created a database with a table which contains commands and their description.My program is:
My class:-DataHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for DataHelper
/// </summary>

    public class DataHelper
    {
        public static string GetData(string Command)
        {
            string Explanation = " ";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CSS-L3-D008;Initial Catalog=works1;Integrated Security=true;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Explanation from Data1 where Command= '" + Command.ToUpper() + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Explanation = dr["Explanation"].ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
            return Explanation;

        }
    }
```

And Service1.asmx

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Private Property DataHelper As Object

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function


    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function GetData(Command) As String

        Return DataHelper.GetData(Command)
    End Function
End Class
```

the problem is that wen i run it i am getting both webmethods HelloWorld and GetData but GetData is not working.When i click HelloWorld() i get invoke method and it runs properly.But when i click GetData() i get invoke button but then it shows
"The test form is only available for methods with primitive types as parameters."
Actually it should give a box where i can enter the command and the description should be returned from the sql server.Please help me.

Comment: Did you read the message? It tells you that what you're attempting is not supported. It has never been supported and it never will be. You cannot invoke that method through the browser. Instead, write a client program to call it. Also, you should stop using ASMX web services, as they're a legacy technology, not meant to be used for new development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should that GetData method in the service declare the type of the Command parameter?:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function GetData(Command As String) As String
    Return DataHelper.GetData(Command)
End Function
```

Comment: ya i did like that and now i am able to run it but now wen i invoke i get error:

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container..ctor(Object Instance)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at MyService2.Service1.GetData(String Command) in c:\documents and settings\sczsc  zsc zsc\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MyService2\MyService2\Service1.asmx